# Overriding qx.core.Object#bind

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

In my application, I've got a key-value store that implements user configuration (a la Apache Commons Configuration):

```
var config = new Configuration();
config.set("foo.bar", "baz");
config.get("foo.bar"); // "baz"
```

Dotted names are used to introduce configuration hierarchy. I also want the following to work:

```
config.bind("foo.bar", target, "property.chain");
```

The idea here is to use traditional qooxdoo binding semantics; the difference is, "foo.bar" does not denote a real property chain, it's merely a key name.

How should I implement this? Is it OK to completely override [`qx.core.Object#bind`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.MBinding~bind) with my implementation? Or should I model the internals of Configuration class such a way that standard [`qx.core.Object#bind`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.MBinding~bind) (delegating to [`qx.data.SingleValueBinding`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.SingleValueBinding~bind)) would work? The second scenario would probably involve some generated classes (similar to what [`qx.data.marshal.Json#toClass`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.data.marshal.Json~toClass) does) to reflect key names with real properties. Frankly, it seems a bit complex to me. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing the binding mechanism is not a trivial task, but it would be unidirectional - for example, while you could override bind() to allow binding *from* your config, you would not be able to bind from some property back *into* the configuration.  Obviously it depends on your application as to whether this is useful, but (for example) if you wanted to build a configuration editor UI, the standard form binding would simply not work.

Alternatively, you could build your configuration object as an actual class and this has several advantages - bi directional binding will work, you can have properties with enforced data types, events, apply methods, you can inspect the structure with reflection, etc.

On the other hand, it is often very useful to be able to create (and forget about) simple settings without having to create a formal API structure for each one.

So ultimately your milage may vary, because it depends on the data that you will want to store, and as your application increases in complexity, the data you wish to store may also get more complex and be harder to store in simple string/value pairs.